# Hibernate: enable first-commit wins and last-commit wins in different modules

Tags: java, hibernate, transactions, persistence

I am having a project with two modules. One will be exposed to user and other not. The other is a batch processing module. Two modules use the same set of model classes.

The module exposed to user needs to use the fist-commit wins strategy so that an StaleObjectStateException will be thrown when an entry is modified concurrently and we can handle it. Whereas in the batch module, it shouldn't need to throw any exception, just the last commit will override the previous one.

But as the two modules use the same model classes, the model classes have hibernating versioning enabled. So that first-commit wins strategy is always enabled.

Is there a way that I can config different strategies for two modules.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you try the below answer? I did not see any accepted answer or comments. Accept / upvote answers if they were helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You need to control it inside the catch block of the `StaleObjectStateException`.

```
try{
    ..............//Your code...
    session.saveOrUpdate(bean);

} catch (StaleObjectStateException e){

        if(forceUpdate){
            long version = getLatestVersionFromDB(bean);
            bean.setVersion(version)
            session.saveOrUpdate(bean);
        }
}
```